# Make numpy matrix more sparse

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, recommendation-engine

Suppose I have a numpy array

```
np.array([
    [3, 0, 5, 3, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 2, 1, 5, 2],
    [4, 3, 5, 3, 1, 4],
    [2, 5, 2, 5, 3, 1],
    [0, 1, 2, 1, 5, 2],
])
```

Now, I want to randomly replace some elements with 0. So that I have an output like this

```
np.array([
    [3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 2, 0, 5, 2],
    [0, 3, 0, 3, 1, 0],
    [2, 0, 2, 5, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 2, 0, 5, 0],
])
```

Comment: Produce a [`mcve`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: you can run this code if you have MovieLens100K dataset. Download it from here files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-100k.zip

Comment: No. **You need to provide** an [mcve]

Comment: That's verifiable.

Comment: It is neither minimal nor complete.

Comment: juanpa.arrivillaga: I have provided my code for how I created a matrix from a dataframe and then calculated its sparsity.

Comment: You can tell me what more I need to tell.

Comment: Create a binary random-matrix and do elementwise multiplication. Depending on your **exact** task, you would need some modification if some a-priori nnz-value is the target (as in this simple approach sampling is independent from the a-priori entry-state).

Comment: @sascha I have update my question and made it more understandable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use [`np.random.choice(..., replace=False)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) to randomly select a number of unique non-zero flattened indices and then simply index and reset those in the input array.

Thus, one solution would be -

```
def make_more_sparsey(a, n):
    # a is input array
    # n is number of non-zero elements to be reset to zero
    idx = np.flatnonzero(a) # for performance, use np.flatnonzero(a!=0)
    np.put(a, np.random.choice(idx, n, replace=False),0)
    return a
```

Sample run -

```
In [204]: R = np.array([
     ...:     [3, 0, 5, 3, 0, 1],
     ...:     [0, 1, 2, 1, 5, 2],
     ...:     [4, 3, 5, 3, 1, 4],
     ...:     [2, 5, 2, 5, 3, 1],
     ...:     [0, 1, 2, 1, 5, 2],
     ...: ])

In [205]: make_more_sparsey(R, n=5)
Out[205]: 
array([[3, 0, 5, 3, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 2],
       [4, 3, 5, 3, 1, 4],
       [2, 5, 0, 5, 3, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2]])
```

Comment: That's very nice.

Comment: @partoftheorigin If `R` is your input array, just do `np.put(R, np.random.choice(idx, n, replace=0),0)`. Don't do : `a = np.put(R..)`. I assumed `a` as the input array. The final result would be a more sparsey `R`.

Comment: Thank you, Divakar!

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.ravel` or the `ravel` method to create a flattened. Note that the `flatten` method always creates a copy, so mutating won't work.

```
a = np.array([
    [3, 0, 5, 3, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 2, 1, 5, 2],
    [4, 3, 5, 3, 1, 4],
    [2, 5, 2, 5, 3, 1],
    [0, 1, 2, 1, 5, 2],
])
r = a.ravel()
r[random.randrange(0, len(r))] = 0
```